# Echo fields of all records in table?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to echo the contents of a table (a product list) yet still have control over the individual fields if possible. While loops did not work as you cannot then go to pick how each field is displayed.

What I am after is to create a product list which then has each record as a hyperlink setting a variable to the product id. Something like:

```
www.domain.com/catalog/product.php?productid=1
```

If there isnt a way to echo the fields individually within each row, how would I be able to get this outcome without adding the link into the database itself for all the products?

Comment: What have you tried? You didn't give us any information regarding the schema of a *product*.

Comment: I think this is a basic information that can be found reading a simple tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its fairly easy

```
  <?php
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
  if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

  mysql_select_db("my_db", $con); 

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Product_List");

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<a href='www.domain.com/catalog  /product.php?productid=".$row['productid']."'>".$row['productid']."</a>";
    echo "<br />";
    }

  mysql_close($con);
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll still need an while loop. Consider this:

```
<?php
$getRows = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM products");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getRows)) {
    echo '<a href="www.domain.com/catalog/product.php?productid=' . $row['id'] . '">Product link</a>';
}
```